# Streaming music over network

Tags: server, streaming, web-development

I am currently developing a little server to store my files (similar to the function of DropBox) with a web interface in php/js. I am using a computer running with Ubuntu server.

I was wondering if it was possible to stream a file over the network (music for example) on a connected device (tv, speakers, etc), directly from the web interface.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: It depends on the web interface.  What are you using?

Comment: Sorry for editing it's my first time on this forum :-) @Daniel, for my web interface, I don't know what you mean but I have created it, without any Api's or anything else (such as XBMC...).

Comment: Are you asking to stream this via your web server? To be able to stream to any device with a browser? Or are you asking about network streaming in general, like DLNA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Kodi to stream, it is constantly changing how you have to do it but here is a guide by now:

1. Create a normal text-file and rename the .txt extension to .strm.
2. Open it up with a text-editor (like gedit).
3. Input the the direct URL-link of the stream.

   This should look like:

   ```
   http://host/path/stream
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   mms://host/path/stream
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   rtsp://host/path/stream
   ```

   (Other protocols are supported such as `http://host/path/to/somefile.mp3`.)
4. Save/copy the .strm file to somewhere where you can open it from Kodi, (like on a SMB/SAMBA, XBMS or UPnP share, or just your local hard drive), like you would with any video/audio file.
5. Open it using play in Kodi under Videos (if it is a video stream) or Music (if it is an audio stream).

If the video stream does not work then the URL-link could be wrong, or possibly the codec/format or the network-protocol it uses it not supported by Kodi.

If you are creating a list of playlists (for example internal and external Shoutcast streams), save the pls or strm files into a directory accessible by Kodi and add the directory as the source, not the files themselves.

More details: http://kodi.wiki/view/Internet_video_and_audio_streams

I haven't use it but there is also Plex wich also suports streaming, here is another guide to do it:
https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200250387-Streaming-Media-Direct-Play-and-Direct-Stream

I am not sure if that is what you want/need as you said you want to do it from a web interface, but i hope it helps as an alternative

Comment: I'm going to vouch for Plex here, because it is just amazing! Plex also has a very nice web interface. Of course, it's mainly used for video streaming, so there might be a simpler solution for audio-only.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using miniDLNA server on my ubuntu box to stream music inside my house.  miniDLNA works with Videos, photos as well.  I can listen to the music on my android phone, on my Windows 10 computers with Windows Media Player, and Ubuntu with XBMC (now it's called Kodi), and on my roku player or on my networked Denen receiver.

It's easy to setup.  Enjoy.