# PulseAudio streaming over network not working

Tags: networking, sound, pulseaudio, debian

I want to use the network to play a mp3 file in the server, and have it playing in all clients headphones (it's a classroom with several PCs).

So I'm trying at home first. I have a Debian Jessie server (with PulseAudio 5.0 installed by default), and an Ubuntu 16.04 as the client (with PulseAudio 8.0 installed by default). Following the instructions [here](http://manurevah.com/blah/en/p/PulseAudio-Sound-over-the-network), I have:

On the server:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
```

that was the only missing part, as attested by `apt-cache policy`. There is no `/etc/default/pulseaudio` on my system, it seems it already starts up automatically. Still added the following lines to `/etc/pulse/system.pa`:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

Then restarted the daemon:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

On the client:

Edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to add the line:

```
load-module module-tunnel-sink-new server=192.168.0.13 sink_name=Remote channels=2 rate=44100
```

where `192.168.0.13` is the IP of the server in the local network. Just like in the server:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

I see in the System Monitor that pulseaudio have correctly restarted in both server and client. But when I play an audio file in the server (for instance, with Audacity), I still couldn't hear anything in the client speakers.

So I installed `paprefs` on Debian (seems not available in Ubuntu Software Center anymore, I only found `pavucontrol` there), and checked both options in Network Server|Enable network access to local sound devices, Multicast/RTP|Enable Multicast/RTP receiver and sender|Send audio from local speakers. Still nothing. Wonder if these `paprefs` options somehow conflict with the first editions in `/etc/pulse/system.pa`?

Of course I'm missing something, but what? I've seen many similar questions over here, but most are years old ([here](https://askubuntu.com/q/93854/416671), [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/28039/416671), [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/176452/416671) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/294190/416671)), and even the [newest one](https://askubuntu.com/q/711387/416671) suggests the installation of new software. I'd really like to use the existing software (i.e. pulseaudio), if possible.

Comment: Looks like after a reboot in both machines, and installing paprefs in Ubuntu it worked. Strange that paprefs don't show in the Software Center app, but is there if you type `sudo apt-get install...`. Isn't it strange?

Comment: that's and answer, could you please copy it from comment to an answer and set as accepted. It will be easier to point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after a reboot in both machines, and installing paprefs in Ubuntu it worked.